# How to access Application Insights data using the Azure API format with AD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights

I can't find an example anywhere!  The format is posted [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats) at the Applications Insights REST API site.  It is only the format and no example.  I think I was able to follow the format, but when I tried it, I got an error message of "Authentication failed.  The 'Authorization' header is missing."  Typically, to get this token, you have to register your app in Azure AD and follow that process.  I don't have an app I need registered.  I want to use *their api/app*.  And the reason I want to use the Azure API format and not the Public API format is to get around the [rate limit](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits).  We need to make requests about once a minute.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you need to create a Service Principle firstly, then use it to get API token message. Please refer to this link: [Use portal to create an Azure Active Directory application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal). You will get client id(app id) and client_secret. You could use the following script to get token(use Power Shell).

```
##get token
$TENANTID="******"
$APPID="<client_id>"
$PASSWORD="<client_secret>"
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token
```

After you get token, you need construct header message. Like below:

```
$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer $token"
    'host'="management.azure.com"
    'contentype'='application/json'
}
```

Then, you could use API to get the information you want.

```
Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url  -Headers $Headers -Method GET
```

Update:

If you want to use  Applications Insights REST API, don't need to use service principle to get token. You need to create a API key. Please refer to this [link](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart/quickstart.markdown).

Comment: @Kendra Ball Maybe I am wrong. You want to use Application Insights API, you also need to get token, you need to create a API key. Please refer to this [link](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart/quickstart.markdown).